# Serialize (and Unserialize) XML List

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm having some issues with serializing some c# fields into an XML file. Below is the code I have:

```
public class Facility
{
    public string ID = "";
    public string Name = "";

    public List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

public class PrefSet
{
    public string SomeItem = "";
    public string AnotherItem = "";
}

public class Config
{
    public string Username = "";
    public string Password = "";

    public List<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }

    public static void SerializeObjectToFile<T>(T dataToSerialize, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.Default);
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                serializer.Serialize(writer, dataToSerialize);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            File.Create(filePath);
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeObjectFromFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T serializedData;

            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                serializedData = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }

            return serializedData;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to configure it so I will have an XML output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Username>admin</Name>
  <Password>123456</VoiceServer>
  <Facilities>
    <Facility>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>First Facility</Name>
      <Profiles>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
      </Profiles>
    </Facility>
    <Facility>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Second Facility</Name>
      <Profiles>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
          <SomeItem>Value</SomeItem>
          <AnotherItem>Value</AnotherItem>
        </Profile>
      </Profiles>
    </Facility>
  </Facilities>
</Config>
```

Notice that there can be multiple Profile and Facility lists.

Here is the code I'm using to execute the serialization:

```
Config config = new Config();
Facility fac = new Facility();
Profile prof = new Profile();

if (File.Exists(CONFIG_FILE)) config = Config.DeserializeObjectFromFile<Config>(CONFIG_FILE);

fac.ID = "1";
fac.Name = "Facility One";
prof.SomeItem = "Value";
prof.AnotherItem = "Value";

config.Facilities.Add(fac);
fac.Profiles.Add(prof);


Config.SerializeObjectToFile<Config>(config, CONFIG_FILE);
```

Additionally, for example, I want to be able to edit and save changes to items.

The issue I'm having is that it will create the XML in the format, but if I change a value, it creates a whole new Facility item instead of updating the existing Facility list item.

Comment: Unclear. Make up your mind about  _"but it's not creating the XML file like I want."_ or _"that it will create the XML in the format"_

Comment: _"but if I change a value"_  show that piece of code too.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I removed the _but it's not creating the XML file like I want._ statement. Regarding your second request, I mean that if I change `prof.SomeItem = "New Value";` instead of updating the old value and replacing it with the new value, it creates a whole new `<Facility>` list with its child items.

Comment: The post only shows adding new items, not the changing. Meaning the most relevant code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

your attribute in your serializable object must be public with properties such as

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

then you can use the [xml] aspects to build your xml structure in your class

example

`[xmlignore]` for stuff you don't want serialized such as methods and functions

```
[xmlnode("Username")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

there are more. you can check the microsoft documentation on xml serialization for all of these.

You might also have to put the `[serializable]` aspect on top of your class.

Comment: The public fields are an eyesore but not the core problem here.